# Why doesn't a simple click: function()... work in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, event-handling

When the user clicks on this element, I want it to show an alert.

However, when I click on the DIV that this Panel generates, nothing happens.

**How can I make an alert execute when the user clicks on the following panel?**

```
var content = new Ext.Panel({
    region:'center',
    margins:'5 0 5 5',
    cls:'empty',
    bodyStyle:'background:ivory; font-size: 13pt',
    html:'<p id="test123">This is where the content goes for each selection.</p>',
    click: function() {
        alert('was clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Did my solution work for you? If not let us know what problems you're still having.

Comment: @McStretch, not exactly as I need it, see below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't accepted an answer, so I'll assume you're still unclear on this.  Here are a few pointers...

First, as coded your Panel will render as a plain square.  If you're expecting it to look like a Panel, you should give it a title (so the title bar will render).

Second, as mentioned, `click` is not a Panel event (it's an Element event).  So you have several ways of getting to the behavior you want.  You can manually attach a listener to the underlying DOM element after the Panel is rendered:

```
Ext.get('txest123').on('click', function(){
    alert('foo');
});
```

You could also do as I mentioned in the comments of another answer to generically handle any body click:

```
// .body is a Panel property for the body element
content.body.on('click', function(){
    alert('foo');
});
```

If you really want to restrict the click to only the child `p` you could add a check:

```
// e is the event object, t is the target DOM node
content.body.on('click', function(e,t){
    if(t.id == 'txest123'){
        alert('clicked the p');
    }
});
```

If I was coding this, I'd probably do something more like this:

```
var content = new Ext.Panel({
    region:'center',
    renderTo: document.body,
    margins:'5 0 5 5',
    cls:'empty',
    title: 'My Panel',
    id: 'txest123',
    bodyStyle:'background:ivory; font-size: 13pt',
    html:'This is where the content goes for each selection.',
    listeners: {
        'render': {
            fn: function() {
                this.body.on('click', this.handleClick, this);
            },
            scope: content,
            single: true
        }
    },
    handleClick: function(e, t){
        alert(this.id); // the panel
        alert(t.innerHTML); // the clicked el
    }
});
```

Now the id is on the Panel (where it should be) and you can use Panel and/or Element methods to access child elements as needed.  It's best to keep id's at the highest level possible.  You'll notice too that the callback function is executed in the scope of the Panel (`scope:this`) so that inside `handleClick` you can treat `this` as the Panel itself and access any of its properties or methods.

So, without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, I can't provide you with the exact code you need.  However, this should hopefully give you some ideas.

**EDIT**: I meant to say this originally... in your code (as posted) you are not actually rendering the Panel.  As I mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182592/how-can-i-get-jquery-javascript-access-to-elements-generated-by-extjs/4212219#4212219) to your related question, if you are adding the Panel as an item to a container that is lazy-rendered, the Panel's DOM won't be available for selection until after the container has rendered it.  In my code above I added `renderTo` so that I don't have this issue, but if you're not doing that you'll have to wait until the Panel is rendered at some time later to access it.

Comment: thanks for these examples, I simplified my code and tried all your suggestions but none seem to work, I posted them all and their error messages here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225389/how-do-i-attach-an-event-handler-to-a-panel-in-extjs

Comment: You can copy and paste this code directly into the Firebug console -- _on a page that has Ext properly loaded_ -- and it works (that's what I did before posting it). You seem to have much bigger conceptual problems going on.  Rather than cut-pasting without understanding what you're doing you really should take a minute to read some tutorials and API docs.

Answer (score 1):

The `Panel` Component does not expose a click event, so the one you're passing into the config never gets fired.

Try putting an id on your Ext.Panel object and then getting its element using `Ext.get()`. Then add a `click` event through `on()`:

```
var content = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'myPanel',
    region:'center',
    margins:'5 0 5 5',
    cls:'empty',
    bodyStyle:'background:ivory; font-size: 13pt',
    html:'<p id="txest123">This is where the content goes for each selection.</p>'
});

Ext.get('myPanel').on('click', function() {alert('You clicked me');});
```

Comment: This will alert on any click within the 'myPanel' DOM element. If you want to restrict click handling to the panel body only (more useful) you could simply do `content.body.on('click', ...)`. But yes, `click` must be handled on an Element, not on the Panel component directly.

Comment: @bmoeskau I tried "Ext.content.body.on('click', function() {alert('was clicked');});" but it caused an error, what syntax do you mean?

Comment: your example doesn't work as is for elements generated by extJS but it does work for elements in the body tag, e.g. this works: `Ext.get('testInHtml').on('click', function() {alert('was clicked');});` when I have this: `<body><p id="testInHtml">this is a test</p></body>`, how can I get this click to work on elements generated by extJS?

Comment: @Edward Tanguay, using bmoeskau's solution would require just content.body.on('click', function(){alert('was clicked');});  Leave off the 'Ext.' at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The following sample is a bit rough but it works for me. It is a panel with a box component, which is showing a thumbnail. When clicking on the thumbnail, it is showing a lightbox with slimbox2. Not pretty, but very effective. The hardcoded images are just for test here.

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        title       : 'Image',
        header      : false,
        frame       : true,
        border      : false,
        bodyStyle   : 'padding : 5px',
        width       : 125,
        items       : [{
            xtype      : 'box',
            height     : 115,
            width      : 115,
            listeners : {
                'render': function() {
                    var id = Ext.id(this);                            
                    Ext.fly(id).addListener('click', function () {
                        jQuery.slimbox('thisisnotanimage', 'CBX');
                    });                            
                }
            },
            autoEl: {
                tag : 'div',
                html : 'somehtmltagstuff' 
            }   
        }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API, click is not a valid event for Panels... However, you should still be able to add the click event to the underlying DIV element.

```
Ext.fly(e.id).addListener('click', Ext.getCmp(e.id) , this);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need something like:

```
var content = new Ext.Panel({
    region:'center',
    margins:'5 0 5 5',
    cls:'empty',
    bodyStyle:'background:ivory; font-size: 13pt',
    html:'<p id="test123">This is where the content goes for each selection.</p>',
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            alert('was clicked');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `click` is not a valid Panel event.