# How do I attach an event handler to a panel in extJS?

Tags: events, extjs, event-handling

All I want to do is **handle a click on an extJS panel**.

I've tried all the of suggestions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166648/why-doesnt-a-simple-click-function-work-in-extjs) plus all I could find elsewhere but **each of them fail** in the ways described below.

**What is the correct syntax to add a click event handler to a extJS panel?**

[**Edit**: For the sake of others who may find this question later, I'll add some comments inline to make this easier to decipher --@bmoeskau]

doesn't execute handler:

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem',
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            alert('ok');
        }
    }
});
```

[Ed: `click` is not a Panel event]

doesn't execute handler:

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem',
    listeners: {
        render: function(c) {
            c.body.on('click', function() {
                alert('ok');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[Ed: The Panel is never being rendered -- add renderTo config.  Next, you'll hit a null error telling you that `c` is not a valid variable. Do you mean `menuItem1` instead?]

doesn't execute handler:

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem'
}); 
Ext.getCmp('panelStart').on('click', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

[Ed: `click` is not a Panel event. Also, the Panel is not yet rendered, so if you switched the callback to be on the element rather than the Component you'd get a null error.]

gets error: Ext.get('panelStart') is null:

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem'
}); 
Ext.get('panelStart').on('click', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

[Ed: It's not rendered, see above. Switching from `getCmp` to `get` means you are switching from referencing the `Component` (which does exist, but does not have a `click` event) to referencing the `Element` (which does have a `click` event, but is not yet rendered/valid).]

makes the panel disappear:

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem',
    listeners: {
        'render': {
            fn: function() {
                this.body.on('click', this.handleClick, this);
            },
            scope: content,
            single: true
        }
    },
    handleClick: function(e, t){
        alert('ok');
    }        
});
```

[Ed: The scope being passed into the callback (`content`) is not a valid ref in this code (this was copy-pasted incorrectly from another sample). Since the Panel var is created as `menuItem1` and the callback is intended to run in the panel's scope, scope var should be `menuItem1`. Also, this Panel is never rendered, see prev comments.]

gives the error "Ext.fly(menuItem1.id) is null":

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem'
}); 
Ext.fly(menuItem1.id).addListener('click', Ext.getCmp(menuItem1.id) , this);
```

[Ed: Panel is not rendered, see above]

...put outside Ext.onReady()...
gets error: Ext.getCmp('panelStart') is null

```
Ext.getCmp('panelStart').on('click', function() {
    alert('okoutside');
});
```

[Ed: Panel is likely not rendered at the time this code is run.  Also, `click` is not a Panel event.]

...put outside Ext.onReady()...
gets error: Ext.get('panelStart') is null

```
Ext.get('panelStart').on('click', function() {
    alert('okoutside');
});
```

[Ed: See above]

...put outside Ext.onReady()...
gets error: Ext.fly('panelStart') is null

```
Ext.fly('panelStart').on('click', function() {
    alert('okoutside');
});
```

[Ed: See above]

For the last three, I checked in Firebug and `<div id="startPanel">` exists:

[image]

## It works with JQuery:

So with JQuery I simply have to do this and it works:

```
$('body').delegate(('#panelStart'), 'click', function(){
    alert('ok with jquery');
});
```

[Ed: This is not a good approach. It's simply delaying attaching of the handler until later, when the element actually shows up in the DOM (which could also be done via Ext btw, but would still not be the proper approach). I spelled out the correct approach, as linked in my answer below.  The OP's attempts are all very close, but each is missing one or two key pieces.]

**How can I attach a click handler like this with extJS?**

Comment: Weird. I tried your third attempt (with "c.body.on") and it works fine. Are you sure that the panel is actually rendering in the first place??? A few tips, the first attempt won't work because click is not a valid event on a panel. I can clearly see the syntax error in the second attempt too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[For anyone else reading this, I went through a fairly thorough explanation of this already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166648/why-doesnt-a-simple-click-function-work-in-extjs/4212059#4212059).]

You are missing a few key concepts:

`click` is **not** a valid Panel event, so adding a click handler on a Panel will do nothing (this is the issue in most of the code you posted above).

In this code:

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
   ...
}); 
content.body
```

You copy-pasted from another answer, but incorrectly.  `content` in the other code referenced the Panel that was created -- it is a variable.  In this code you created the Panel as `menuItem1` but then are trying to reference it as `content`?

Please re-read my previous explanation about how rendering works in the other answer I gave you. You **must** either add a Panel to a container that renders it, **or** render it directly (via the `renderTo` config).  If you do neither, the Panel will not show up.

Using jQuery's delegate function is **not** the proper approach with Ext JS components.

Comment: great, thanks for all the comments, I'll work through your comments to get a solution to work in my code so I can replace the jquery approach. It makes me wonder though: why the Panel is so difficult to attach a click event to, I have been able to get quickly up to speed with handlers on **buttons** and **grid rows** with "handler..." and "listeners..." but the panel seems to be such a special case.

Comment: The Panel is not a special case -- it's just that the 'click' event does not make sense for the entire Panel, as a Component (it makes perfect sense for a button, grid row, or other Components).  As such, it is not exposed via the Panel API.  DOM events are always available on DOM nodes, but they are only made available via the Component event API when it makes sense to do so.  In your case `myPanel.body.on('click', ...);` is the correct approach, just make sure the panel is rendered before doing it.

Comment: this makes sense now, I was getting a `menuItem1.header is undefined` error but only when I would include menuItem1 in an accordion layout, the trick is to put the `menuItem1.header.on('click',...)` AFTER the definition of the accordion layout since only then does the menuItem1 exist, thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: @bmoeskau The new easy way to do it is `listeners: {click:{element: 'body, fn: function(){}'}}`

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (comp) {
            var element = comp.getEl();
            element.on('click', function() {
                alert('ok')
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This code will do nothing until the Panel is actually rendered, either via `renderTo` or by adding it to a container that renders it.  Also, the `afterrender` code is not really a very good approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Well, I assumed this wasn't the complete code - only a snippet. I also think it's pretty obvious that this code won't do anything until after it's rendered...the 'afterrender' listener kind of implies that.  This approach does work, but I'll certainly accept that maybe it's not a "good approach" (was just the first thing that came to mind).  Perhaps you could add a comment here on why this isn't a good approach.  Thanks.

Comment: I clarified about rendering because the OP obviously does not understand this.  Some of his null errors are obviously due to the Panel never being rendered, and in the code he posted in his original questions, he was attaching listeners to Panel's internal elements prior to adding the panel into a container that renders it. This code will work OK, but a better approach would be to assign the handler as a separate function on the Panel rather than an anonymous fn. continued to next comment...

Comment: Also, rather than handling clicks on a Panel's el directly, it's usually preferable to target a specific child, like the body. The Panel already has internal click handling, e.g. in the header bar, so you may run into issues handling clicks on the underlying el (and also you normally would not want to respond to clicks in the header/footer in app code).  Most likely the OP actually wants something like `myPanel.body.on('click', ...)` where myPanel has already been rendered. Note that this could be in the render/afterrender callback too, as you show.

Comment: Oh sure...go for the whole "teach a man to fish" approach!  :)

Comment: @Gerrat This works, but there's a new simpler way to do it, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to listen to events on Ext.Elements inside of a panel, you use the `element` property when calling `addListener` or passing in `listeners` config, instead of waiting for the `afterrender` event just to set the listeners

```
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'panelStart',
    title: 'Start',
    html: 'This is the start page.',
    cls:'menuItem',
    listeners: {
        click: {
           element: 'el', // could be 'body', or any other Ext.Elements 
                          // that are available from the component
           fn: function() {}
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a more simple approach:

```
    listeners: { 'expand': {fn: adminSelected }}
```